# Why writer for media type application/json missing

Tags: java, json, resteasy

Basically I have a restful service (post) that consumes(`application/json`) and produces  (`application/json`). The single param for this service is an annotated java object.

I am using `org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest` to send the request to the service. However, I am getting this exception in the client end and the exception:

> could not find writer for content-type `application/json` type.

Does this mean that I am missing some library jars or I have to write my own writer for application/json?

I am using resteasy 1.1

Mark

Comment: [ClientRequest, how to serialize POJO's to json data correctly? could not find writer for content-type application/json type:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18113749/1817029

Answer (score 9):

Raman is correct. Jettison is a valid option. You can also use Jackson.
If you are using maven, it is as simple as including the following dependency in you pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

At which point you should have no problem writing code such as:

```
    SomeBean query = new SomeBean("args")
    request.body("application/json", query);
    ClientResponse response = request.post();
```

Answer (score 2):

actually I had the same problem, I did solve it by adding jettison provider for application/json mime type. I don't know whether resteasy 1.1 containts jettison provider but version 1.2 does.
Also if you are using jdk 1.6 you must exclude javax.xml.stream:stax-api jar file, otherwise you will have a problem.

Here is the example:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name="account")
public class Account {

    private Long id;
    private String accountNo;


    public Account(){}
    public Account(String no)   {
        accountNo=no;
    }


    @Id
    @XmlElement
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getAccountNo() {
        return accountNo;
    }
    public void setAccountNo(String a) {
        accountNo = a;
    }

}
```

and JAXB class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;


    @Path("/account")
    public class AccountService {


        @GET
        @Path("/{accountNo}")
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Account getAccount(@PathParam("accountNo") String accountNo) {
                   return new Account(accountNo);
        }

    }
```

That's all, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Add below to the Resource class or the method causing the exception

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```