# REST Java client unable to invoke request

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, wildfly

I've written a REST service, I test it with Firefox that displayes JSON format of my objects. But when I invoke the same URL with a simple REST Java client I get the following error when I run it with JUnit:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:195)
    at ma.gesto.persistence.TestRESTServices.createAndDeleteAReference(TestRESTServices.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
**Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: ma.gesto.entity.Reference**
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:40)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:117)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:341)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:558)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.buildEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:281)
    ... 26 more
```

This is my code:

```
public class TestRESTServices {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/ma.ge.persistence-1.0/rest/reference";
    private static URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(BASE_URL).port(8080).build();
    private static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    @Test
    public void createAndDeleteAReference() {

        Reference r = ReferenceFactory.createReference("DummyName",
                "dummyDesc", 1.7);
        Response response = client.target(uri).request().post(Entity.entity(r, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Comment: could you post the code of your rest services ?
or, did you try that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365515/resteasy-could-not-find-writer-for-content-type-application-json-type ?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Vincent, and this is the solution. I was missing a dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```