# Log4j2 configuration not found when running standalone application built by shade plugin

Tags: java, log4j2, maven-shade-plugin

I have application which when I run from maven log4j2 it is working:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.args=...
```

but when I run jar as standalone application  then it shows error:

```
java -jar
```

log:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
```

I dont understand this error. It shows that log4j2 configuration file is not found but also complain about some format which is probably in configuration file

My configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="off">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p - %-26.26c{1} - %m\n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>

        <Logger name="my.package" level="DEBUG" /> 

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and it is located in root directory of jar file.

UPDATE

jar is created by maven shade plugin:

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
```

so it contains all necessary libraries (about 23 MB) and when I run this jar I just need to specify arguments

Comment: Can you given some info about how you build your jar file - is it a fat jar, or if not, how you supply the classpath when you execute it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue while building the fat jar using "maven-assembly-plugin" can you suggest something?

Comment: @bestwishes Did you managed to find the solution? 
I have the same issue and the solutions below are not working for me. thanks

Comment: For those who are facing the same issue with maven-assembly-plugin" change version to 2.6 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ok I found this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-673) about this problem.

In short, the problem arises when application classes are packaged in uber jar using maven shade plugin. 
While for `log4j2` version `2.8.1` the fix is still pending, the suggested workaround is to update maven `pom.xml` with extra configuration settings for shade plugin as follow:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        . . . . .

        <build>
            . . . . . 
            <plugins>
                . . . . . 
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer"/>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                            <version>2.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                . . . . . 
            </plugins>
        . . . . . 
        </build>
        . . . . . 
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
                <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>      
        . . . . . 
    </project>
```

Comment: add this to what file?

Comment: to pom.xml where u have shade plugin

Comment: @hudi How about if I use ant?

Comment: What does the plugin exactly do?

Answer (score 6):

Please refer this for the complete example of pom.file.

In addition to the answer given by @hudi,
we need to add dependencies inside the plugin for the transformation.

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>               
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>com.auto.facade.RunMain</Main-Class>
                    <Build-Number>123</Build-Number>
                </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer" />                
          </transformers>
          <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
         </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
  </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by adding the following line in the run configuration.

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\deploy\bin\log4j2.xml
```

My Log4j version is

> 2.12.1

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <finalName>project-name-product-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>your.main.classname</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ComponentsXmlResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer" />

                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Though it might be more useful if you explain what it does hand how it solves the OP's problem.