# Could not find writer for content-type application/xml type

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I am following this solution to try and eliminate my issue, but am failing miserably: [RESTEasy: Could not find writer for content-type application/json type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365515/resteasy-could-not-find-writer-for-content-type-application-json-type)

Here are my maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a XML class that I created that I marshall/unmarshall.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Cools")
public class CoolXml {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Boolean isCool;

    public Boolean getIsCool() {
        return isCool;
    }

    public void setIsCool(final Boolean isCool) {
        this.isCool = isCool;
    }
}
```

When calling the endpoint with this code, the last line generates the error:

```
final String url = "http://localhost:8080/sample/getcools";
final ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(url);
request.header(HttpHeaderNames.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
final CoolXml req = new CoolXml(project);
request.body("application/xml", req);
final ClientResponse<CoolXmlResponse> response = request.post(CoolXmlResponse.class);
```

I get the super annoying error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: could not find writer for content-type application/xml type: cool.CoolXml
```

Do I need any additional dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, I ended up using the following classes to test a request:

```
final Client client = Client.create();
final WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
final CoolXml requestXml = new CoolXml();
... some data setting
final ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml").post(ClientResponse.class, requestXml);
```