# RestEasy Client giving could not find writer for content-type application/xml type

Tags: java, xml, jboss, jaxb, resteasy

I am writing a test client for my endpoint, but it is not able to execute the connection giving

```
EXCEPTION : could not find writer for content-type application/xml type: com.gepower.gees.ifs.goet.porequest.model.CreatePOReq
```

in the line

```
ClientResponse<CreatePOResp> clientResponse = client.post(CreatePOResp.class);
```

From Postman, the endpoint is returning the result fine.
I have tried to add all the RestEasy jars in my project, but it is still giving the same error while

```
public static CreatePOResp createUpdateALFPO(CreatePOReq req) {
    CreatePOResp response = new CreatePOResp();
    String operation = "createUpdatePO";

    try {

        String xmlReq = "";
        try {
            xmlReq = XmlUtils.marshalXmlToString(req);
            System.out.println(operation + " - XML SOAP REQUEST: " + xmlReq);
        } catch (Exception xmlex) {
            System.out.println(xmlex.getMessage());
        }
        ClientRequest client = new ClientRequest("http://localhost/ofsrestws/fs/porequest/addpo");

        client.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, req);
        System.out.println("URI ====" + client.getUri());
        ClientResponse<CreatePOResp> clientResponse = client.post(CreatePOResp.class);
        ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance().addBuiltInMessageBodyReader(new JAXBXmlTypeProvider());

        if (clientResponse.getStatus() == 200) {
            response = clientResponse.getEntity();
            System.out.println("web service is OK");
            return response;
        } else {
            System.out.println("an issue has occure during the call of the web service: "
                    + clientResponse.getResponseStatus());
            // Object resp = clientResponse.getResponseStatus();

            return null;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION : " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION : " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {}
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not find writer for content-type application/xml type: com.gepower.gees.ifs.goet.porequest.model.CreatePOReq
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.writeRequestBody(ClientRequest.java:409)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClientExecutor$ClientRequestEntity.<init>(ApacheHttpClientExecutor.java:117)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClientExecutor.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClientExecutor.java:188)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClientExecutor.execute(ApacheHttpClientExecutor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.execute(ClientRequest.java:378)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.httpMethod(ClientRequest.java:590)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.post(ClientRequest.java:496)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.post(ClientRequest.java:501)
    at org.tcs.TestJava.createUpdateALFPO(TestJava.java:52)
    at org.tcs.TestJava.main(TestJava.java:31)
```

[image]

**Please find the list of dependencies**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is generally a dependency issue. Are you sure you have resteasy-jaxb-provider in the classpath?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111268/could-not-find-writer-for-content-type-application-xml-type 
If that doesn't fix it, please let us know what dependencies are you using.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot -resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.0.9.Final.jar is there

Comment: Added the list of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is that you register the adapter after you make the post request:

```
ClientResponse<CreatePOResp> clientResponse = client.post(CreatePOResp.class);
ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance().addBuiltInMessageBodyReader(new JAXBXmlTypeProvider());
```

Since the exception occurs in the post call, maybe you should try switching the order.

I notice that you are using the deprecated RestEasy client API. Note that the JAX-RS 2.0 client implementation will automatically load all available
Provider classes (through the service loader mechanism). Maybe you should consider using that API instead.