# RestEasy Client Exception - Cannot serialize object to JSON

Tags: java, json, maven, resteasy

Edit:  I saw the "duplicate" question but I do not have a dependency problem.  I think it has something to do with not running in a container or using the MVN shade plugin to generate a "fat" jar.

I have this code calling a service - I know the service works b/c I can call via CURL.  The issue is that the `ResteasyClient` is not recognizing the jackson-mapper serializer (I think):

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
String endpoint = ClientUtil.getEndpoint();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(endpoint);
IService simple = target.proxy(IService.class);
IAlertFact alertFact = ClientUtil.propertiesToAlertFact(alertProperties);
Response response = simple.processAlert(alertFact);
```

Here are the maven deps:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I thought having the `resteasy-jackson-provider` on the classpath would do the trick, but I keep getting this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: com.myproject.AlertFact
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:40)
```

Is there something I have to do to the `ResteasyClientBuilder` to make it use Jackson, or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RESTEasy: Could not find writer for content-type application/json type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365515/resteasy-could-not-find-writer-for-content-type-application-json-type)

Comment: Thanks, I did actually search before posting that, that does not solve my issue.