# AWS lambda performing http request with RestEasy: could not find writer for content-type application/json type

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, resteasy

I'm currently developing an Alexa skill using serverless lambda.
My skill performs an http request to trigger some action.

For this I'm using RestEasy. My problem is that I always receive an exception when executing the request in aws lambda. Executing from within my IDE works (small main method to test). Maybe the IDE is fetching some additional stuff.

```java
 Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: at.tsul.dev.f4l.uni.asterics.astericsAlexaFunction.client.AlexaRequestJson
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:297)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:67)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:226)
    at at.tsul.dev.f4l.uni.asterics.astericsAlexaFunction.client.AstericsClient.performRequest(AstericsClient.java:29)
    at at.tsul.dev.f4l.uni.asterics.astericsAlexaFunction.handlers.MouseActionIntent.handle(MouseActionIntent.java:25)
    at at.tsul.dev.f4l.uni.asterics.astericsAlexaFunction.handlers.MouseActionIntent.handle(MouseActionIntent.java:12)
    at com.amazon.ask.request.handler.adapter.impl.BaseHandlerAdapter.execute(BaseHandlerAdapter.java:55)
    at com.amazon.ask.request.dispatcher.impl.BaseRequestDispatcher.doDispatch(BaseRequestDispatcher.java:177)
    at com.amazon.ask.request.dispatcher.impl.BaseRequestDispatcher.dispatch(BaseRequestDispatcher.java:110)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: at.tsul.dev.f4l.uni.asterics.astericsAlexaFunction.client.AlexaRequestJson
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:302)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.syncProceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:240)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:224)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:444)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:601)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.buildEntity(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:560)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.loadHttpMethod(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:465)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:275)
    ... 17 more
```

I've the following dependencies:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
            <artifactId>ask-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.37.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

In the dependency tree I don't see any any version mismatches or similar, probably as I'm using the resteasy-bom.

This is the code to perform the request:

```java
 public static AlexaResponseJson performRequest (AlexaRequestJson json) {
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl()//
                .connectTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)//
                .readTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)//
                .build();

        String url = System.getenv("astericsUrl");
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(url);

        AstericsEndpoint asterics = target.proxy(AstericsEndpoint.class);
        AlexaResponseJson response = asterics.triggerAction(json);

        client.close();
        return response;
    }
```

The *Json classes are just plain POJOs. and the AstericsEndpoint class just defines the endpoint (EDIT1: defining the url, POST method and consumes/produces application/json).

So my question is, am I missing something? Is there still a dependency missing allthough it works when directly invoked from a main method in the same workspace. Or am I doing the export wrong (assembly plugin:single goal with jar-with-dependencies descriptor ref). I checked that directly in the generated jar, there are all required dependencies in there.
Best regards
suizi

EDIT2: I've already tried out and reviewed different questions on here, and also this one: [RESTEasy: Could not find writer for content-type application/json type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365515/resteasy-could-not-find-writer-for-content-type-application-json-type) . I may be wrong, but I think this is a slightly different issue, as json creating and parsing works but not in AWS lambda environment.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've already tried these dependencies. (see EDIT2 in question)

Comment: no I'm not executing it the same way. I invoked the function from within the IDE by creating a small main method.
Good point. thank you. I'll try executing the jar.

Comment: okay: checked it by executing the jar. seems a problem with packaging. I'll dive into it after work. and check back on you