# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: com.test.Request

Tags: jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS to develop an endpoint, I have the following class:

```
public class Request implements Serializable {
  private String key;
  private Content content;
  private List<String> user;
}
```

And this is the endpoint that is configured:

```
@Path("/api/v1")
public class MyAPI {
  
  @POST
  @Path("/alerts")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  String postAlerts(Request request) throws WebApplicationException{
      //Implementation
  }
}
```

When I invoke the end point from client, I get following exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: com.test.Request
```

I have included all the dependencies mentioned in [RESTEasy: Could not find writer for content-type application/json type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365515/resteasy-could-not-find-writer-for-content-type-application-json-type). Specifically [resteasy-jaxrs, jaxrs-api, resteasy-jaxb-provider, resteasy-jackson2-provider] and I am able to verfiy that they are present in the classpath. Do I need provide some annotations on the 'Request' class which would create a writer for that for content-type application/json?

Comment: This is a writer error, meaning outgoing. Either outgoing on the client side or outgoing on the server side. You code shows the Request object on the inbound side and a String on the outbound. So the error message doesn't match the code your're showing.

Comment: I am actually getting it on client. Here is the client code that calls it: myApi.postAlert(new Request(key, content, userList))

Comment: If you have the required JSON provider dependency for the client, and you are still getting the error, then try to manually register the provider. It might not be automatically registered for some reason. Just do `client.register(JacksonJsonJaxbProvider.class)`