# How to get Arquillian remote to work with Glassfish 5, and Netbeans 8?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, netbeans-8, jboss-arquillian, glassfish-5

I am trying to follow a tutorial for Java EE and Arquillian.  I am running java sdk 8, Glassfish5 , and I am working on NetBeans. After modifying my POM, so I could get resteasy to work I am able to deploy and run the packaged test, but I am now experiencing the following error.

The Error Message

```
createBook(com.tutorial.bookstore.rest.BookEndpointTest)  Time elapsed: 0.396 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
    at com.tutorial.bookstore.rest.BookEndpointTest.createBook(BookEndpointTest.java:86)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: com.tutorial.bookstore.model.Book
    at com.tutorial.bookstore.rest.BookEndpointTest.createBook(BookEndpointTest.java:86)
```

My Test

```
package com.tutorial.bookstore.rest;


import com.tutorial.bookstore.model.Book;
import com.tutorial.bookstore.model.Language;
import com.tutorial.bookstore.repository.BookRepository;
import com.tutorial.util.IsbnGenerator;
import com.tutorial.util.NumberGenerator;
import com.tutorial.util.TextUtil;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.RunAsClient;
import org.jboss.arquillian.extension.rest.client.ArquillianResteasyResource;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
import static javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@RunAsClient
public class BookEndpointTest {

    // ======================================
    // =             Attributes             =
    // ======================================

    private static String bookId;
    private Response response;

    // ======================================
    // =             Deployment             =
    // ======================================

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static Archive<?> createDeploymentPackage() {

        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClass(Book.class)
            .addClass(Language.class)
            .addClass(BookRepository.class)
            .addClass(NumberGenerator.class)
            .addClass(IsbnGenerator.class)
            .addClass(TextUtil.class)
            .addClass(BookEndpoint.class)
            .addClass(JAXRSConfiguration.class)
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
    }

    // ======================================
    // =            Test methods            =
    // ======================================

    @Test
        public void createBook(@ArquillianResteasyResource("api/books") WebTarget webTarget) {

         // Creates a book
        Book book = new Book("isbn", "a  title", 12F, 123, Language.ENGLISH, new Date(), "imageURL", "description");
        response = webTarget.request(APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(book, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        assertEquals(CREATED.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());


    }



}
```

My current POM looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstore-back</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>bookstore-back</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Test -->
        <version.junit>4.12</version.junit>
        <version.arquillian>1.1.13.5</version.arquillian>
        <version.shrinkwrap>1.2.6</version.shrinkwrap>
        <version.arquillian.rest>1.0.0.Alpha4</version.arquillian.rest>
        <version.resteasy>3.1.2.Final</version.resteasy>
        <!-- Plugins -->
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.19.1</version.surefire.plugin>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-universe</artifactId>
                <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>




    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TEST -->
        <!--START ==> Needed for arquillian remote testing on glassfish-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arquillian.universe</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit</artifactId>
            <!--  <version>${version.arquillian}</version> -->
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
            <version>${version.shrinkwrap}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-rest-client-impl-3x</artifactId>
            <version>${version.arquillian.rest}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${version.resteasy}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <!--END ==> Needed for arquillian rest client testing-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>bookstore-back</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <!-- <arquillian.launch>arquillian-wildfly-remote</arquillian.launch> -->
                        <arquillian.launch>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</arquillian.launch> 
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you are using? Also, with respect to the RESTEasy exception you are getting, you may be able to resolve that by adding dependencies to your pom. See [RESTEasy: Could not find writer for content-type application/json type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365515/resteasy-could-not-find-writer-for-content-type-application-json-type) and [Why writer for media type application/json missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630827/why-writer-for-media-type-application-json-missing)

Comment: The tutorial is on Pluralsight, I’ll search GitHub and see if the author has it published there for the public.

Comment: Here you go someone else posted the code. The major difference is that I’m using java 8 and I’m using a GlassFish server.  https://github.com/xmarlem/bookstore-back

Comment: Great, thx. I think that adding the right dependency(s) to pom.xml should resolve this....